# T-SQL How to build an aggregate table based on max values from a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to build a high-level summary of a customer's most purchased product based on an aggregate table.

The table takes the below format

```
account_code    product_id   num_purchases
abc123          1            10
abc123          2            5
xyz789          1            5
```

and I want to return the below

```
account_code    product_id   
abc123          1           
xyz789          1
```

so for each account, the product id of the most purchased product for that account is returned.

I've so far struggled with this, however I feel there must be a fairly basic solution, any assistance greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  account_code, product_id
FROM    (
            SELECT  account_code, product_id, num_purchases,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY account_code 
                                        ORDER BY num_purchases DESC) RowID
            FROM    TableName
        )records
WHERE   RowID = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44c9f/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════════╦════════════╗
║ ACCOUNT_CODE ║ PRODUCT_ID ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╣
║ abc123       ║          1 ║
║ xyz789       ║          1 ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tableName.account_code, tableName.product_ID
FROM tableName INNER JOIN  (
SELECT account_code, max(num_purchases) AS maxPurchases
FROM tableName
GROUP BY account_code) AS aggregated
ON tableName.account_code  = aggregated.account_code
AND tableName.num_purchases = aggregated.maxpurchases
```

Using fiddle from JW -> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44c9f/13